# How do I don't duplicate properties over 2 methods?

Tags: php, oop

I have something like this

```
<?php
class Advertising{
    private $param1;
    private $param2;

    public function __construct($param1, $param2){
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        $this->param2 = $param2;
    }

    public function newCustomer($raw_data1, $raw_data2){
        $raw_data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data1);
        $raw_data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data2);

        // Now I would use these properties, as it are clean.
    }

    public function editCustomer($raw_data1, $raw_data2){
        $raw_data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data1);
        $raw_data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data2);

        // Now I would use these properties, as it are clean.
    }

    public function newStore($raw_data3, $raw_data4){
        $raw_data3 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data3);
        $raw_data4 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data4);

        // Now I would use these properties, as it are clean.
    }

    public function editStore($raw_data3, $raw_data4){
        $raw_data3 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data3);
        $raw_data4 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data4);

        // Now I would use these properties, as it are clean.
    }

    // As you can see here, there's 2 pair of methods. The one that creates a new element, and the another that modify it. There's common properties each other, but not with the another methods.
}
```

I can't pass those properties such as $raw_data1, and $raw_data2 through __construct, because it's used to treat all common code, not a single and specific methods, in this case.

Comment: I dont understand your problem. Your methods are parametrized, so you can pass data for each of them. Isn't that what you ask for?

Comment: As you are doing the same implementation as "mysql_real_escape_string" in different methods, you can pass those params into __construct($param1, $param2) and inside that, you can assign to another variable after doing mysql_real_escape_string. Like below
============
    public function __construct($param1, $param2){
        $this->param1 = mysql_real_escape_string($param1);
        $this->param2 = mysql_real_escape_string($param2);
    }

Comment: Just stop using the deprecated mysql-API. Use e.g. [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO) and [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: have you solved this Jack?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want the newXxx functions to save the data in the class as properties so that the editXxx functions can change them?

If so would this be any help?

```
class Advertising{
    private $param1;
    private $param2;

    public $Customer = NULL;

    public function __construct($param1, $param2){
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        $this->param2 = $param2;
    }

    public function newCustomer($raw_data1, $raw_data2){
        $this->Customer = new Customer();

        $this->Customer->data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data1);
        $this->Customer->data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($raw_data2);

        // Now I would use these properties, as it are clean.
    }

    public function editCustomer($new_data1, $new_data2){
        if ( isset($this->Customer) ) {
            $this->Customer->data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($new_data1);
            $this->Customer->data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($new_data2);
        } else {
            // report error
        }
        // Now I would use these properties, as it are clean.
    }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @djc in fact it's a pretty much good evaluation of what very confused op wants to do... why don't you let op decide for themselves is something is an answer or not?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Why thank you Sir. I thought it was at least a reasonable attempt at reading between the lines.